# MVC 4: return selected dropdownbox value to a Controller

Tags: controller, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownbox

I have a question about how to return the selected dropdownbox value to a Controller.

The problem is that I use 2 different models. I'll try to explain.

For this usecase I use the following entity's in the database: Projects and Courses.
Projects has a number of attributes and navigational properties. One of the navigational properties is Courses.

In the View it shows a dropdownbox of all the existing courses in the database.
So what I would like to do is to select a Course and then add it to the project.(using it's ID)
But I can't figure out how to return the selected value to the Controller.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post code of both models and the signature of the controller method that is going to receive the data? I know how to help you but I'd like to see your code so I can give you a concrete answer. (Welcome to SO!)

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you just have to put this code :

```
@model Projects

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Courses, "CourseID", "CourseName"))
```

You just need to have a field `CourseID` in your model `Projects` and a controller like this in order to handle the form :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(Projects projects) {
    // Here you have projects.CourseID filled with the correct value
}
```